# How to format regexes in find-name-dired?

Tags: emacs

When calling `M-x find-name-dired` you will be prompted for a root directory and a filename pattern.

What's the proper find regex for multiple file extensions? Eg using `*(txt|html)` gets converted to `find . \( -iname \*\(coffee\|html\) \) -ls`, which doesn't work. Is there any way to convert to the `-o` or `-regex` mentioned here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-name` argument comes from a variable, so that can easily be overridden in code:

```el
(defun my-find-regex-dired ()
  "Like `find-name-dired', but using -regex instead of -name"
  (interactive)
  (let ((find-name-arg "-regex"))
    (call-interactively 'find-name-dired)))
```

or you could make a copy of `find-name-dired` and edit it as desired.

But I'd suggest just using `M-x find-dired` which gives you full control over the arguments.

Comment: plus1 for find-dired